# Is there any way to use thrust with cufftComplex data type when the data is in device?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I'm making program where I have 4D data. In a loop I iterate through the 4th dimension, and take the 3D data which is originally `float`, I convert that data to `cufftComplex` and then copy it to device and do several device operations like fourier transform(from `cufft` library), image denoising(my own cuda kernel). While being in that loop in the between these operations after the fourier transform I want find the median of the 3D data in that particular iteration.

I know thrust allows me to do sorting from which I can easily find the median value like in the following example with a normal `float` data type I do

```
int row, column, slice;
row = 5;
column = 5;
slice = 5;
int alloc_size = row*column*slice;
float * theMainData = new float[alloc_size];
srand(time(NULL));
for(int k=0; k<slice; k++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<column; j++)
    {
       for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
       {
          theMainData[i+(j*column)+(k*row*column)] = rand()%1000;;
       }
    }
}
thrust::sort(theMainData, theMainData + alloc_size);
float median = theMainData[(alloc_size/2)];
cout<<endl<<"The median value is "<<median<<endl;
```

So, now my question is, is there any way to make `thrust::sort()` function work with `cufftComplex` when the data already copied to the device? Or is there any other function similar to `thrust` which can deal with `cufftComplex` data type when the data is already copied to the device?

Comment: Of course there is no ordering in the complex domain and even if you sort against the magnitude this will not be an ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, now my question is, is there any way to make thrust::sort() function work with cufftComplex when the data already copied to the device?

Yes.

[Thrust](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) provides [versions](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__sorting.html#gad39e37d88f8334cbdd3e047a53e5cfba) of the `sort` operation that accept user defined comparison operators, to order the data any way you wish.

An example usage with a custom functor is given in the thrust [sorting example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/sort.cu) (using the `evens_before_odds` functor).

So you'll need a comparison functor.  I don't know how you sort complex values, but as an example if you wanted to sort them based on the magnitude you could do:

```
#include <cuComplex.h>
#include <cufft.h>


struct my_complex_sort
{
  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(cufftComplex x, cufftComplex y)
  {
    return (cuCabs(x) > cuCabs(y));
  }
};
```

If you already have `cufftComplex` data on the device, you could create a thrust pointer for it.  Let's suppose the pointer to your device data is `d_data` and the data size is `N`:

```
thrust::device_ptr<cufftComplex> dp_data = thrust::device_pointer_cast(d_data);
```

Then you could sort the data with:

```
thrust::sort(dp_data, dp_data+N, my_complex_sort());
```

(disclaimer: coded in browser, not tested)